# Create and open PDF in new tab

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf, html2canvas

In my application I got a button that creates a pdf using html2canvas and jsPDF.
I'd like the new downloaded pdf be opened in new tab. I cannot figure out how to open newly downloaded file.

Is this even possible to do?

**This is my code.**

```
print() {
        const fileName = String(new Date().valueOf());
        const element: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('.print-area');
        const regionCanvas = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        html2canvas(element, { scale: 3 }).then(async canvas => {
            const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
            pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 3, 0, 205, (205 / regionCanvas.width) * regionCanvas.height);
            await pdf.save(fileName, { returnPromise: true });

            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = fileName;
            // this points to non existing file
            document.body.appendChild(a);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to download and open a file. 
You have to basically call two functions:

```
pdf.save(fileName);
window.open(pdf.output('bloburl', { filename: fileName }), '_blank');
```

So the code in the end looks like this:

```
print() {
        const fileName = String(new Date().valueOf());
        const element: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('.print-area');
        const regionCanvas = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        html2canvas(element, { scale: 3 }).then(async canvas => {
            const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
            pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 3, 0, 205, (205 / regionCanvas.width) * regionCanvas.height);
            await pdf.save(fileName, { returnPromise: true });
            window.open(pdf.output('bloburl', { filename: fileName }), '_blank');
        });
    }
```